# Scala Streams Performance

Tags: scala, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

A canonical example of the usefulness of recursive algebraic data types and the lazy evaluation  is a game algorithm, e.g. as shown in the famous WhyFP paper by John Hughes (*Comp. J., Vol. 32, No. 2, 1989*).

Implementing it with Scala, and using lazily evaluated `Stream[Tree[A]]` for each subtree of a game leads to `trait Tree[A]` with a definition:

```
sealed trait Tree[A]
case class Branch[A](ts: Stream[Tree[A]]) extends Tree[A]
case class Leaf[A](a: A) extends Tree[A]
```

Now a lazily evaluated, possibly infinite, game can be presented as:

```
gameTree(b: Board): Tree[Board] = 
  if (b.isAtEndPos) Leaf(b) 
  else Branch(b.emptySlots.toStream.map((pos: Int) => gameTree(b addTic pos)))
```

and you can implement a pruning, scoring and parallelization strategy to the 
the actual algorithm, that is for example *minimax* which does the job, and
evaluates the parts of the tree which are necessary:

```
def maximize(tree: Tree[Board]): Int = tree match {
  case Leaf(board) => board.score
  case Branch(subgames) => 
     subgames.map((tree: Tree[Board]) => minimize(tree)).max
} ...
def minimize // symmetrically
```

However, the infinite stream introduces a significant performance penalty, and solving identical game tree using eager list (`ts: List[Tree[A]]`) is 25 times more efficient.

Is there any way to use Streams or lazy structures in Scala effectively in similar situations?

Edit: added some performance results, and actual code: 
In [link](http://bit.ly/A9coNy) is the lazy version.

Lazy version (scala 2.9.1):
`Time for gametree creation: 0.031s and for finding the solution 133.216s.`

No conversions in the tree creation, i.e. mapping over sets in *minimax*
`Time for gametree creation: 4.791s and for finding the solution 6.088s.`

Converting to list in the gameTree creation
`Time for gametree creation: 4.438s and for finding the solution 5.601s.`

Comment: "is 25 times more efficient" -- care to post a project with both variations and the benchmarking rig?

Comment: Can't reproduce on my machine. I get, for creation/solution: `Stream`s: 0.024s/6.568s, `List`s: 4.189s/5.382s. So `Stream`s are faster for me (when you add up both times).

Comment: I get very similar results as Philippe; Stream: 0.23s/6.12s vs List: 4.07s/5.16s.  So it seems as if Streams actually perform better in this case.  I'm also using scala 2.9.1, so the only differences I can think about are either a different JVM, different JVM settings, or some strange hardware-dependent issues.

Comment: I did not pinpoint the actual problem yet, but running the performance tests and the question was sloppy, since with a different cleanly installed environment, and reasonable gc opts set, I did not stumble into streams performance. 

I did have same kind of problem earlier about one year ago (in a different environment, and hw), with a simple implementation of folding a stream instead of a range, (although continuation passing was clearly the slowest). Thus I did not suspect, that env would be the root cause. Sorry about that.

Thanks to all for your effort!

Comment: @jrosti The link is broken

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get a quick and rough idea of where the time goes, you can try to run:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xprof" scala TicTacToe
```

As stated in the comments, I for one cannot reproduce your experience.